# Do Vim Controls Outside Vim Exist?

Tags: linux, vim

I've been using Vim, in addition to the add-on called `Vimium` for Chrome on Linux Mint. I find it very enjoyable and productive to scroll pages with `hjkl` and search with `/`.

Unfortunately, this functionality is not system-wide. I'm asking whether there exists any daemon, kernel module, or driver (or anything, really) that mimics or remaps the entire system such that it operates just like Vim.

What I mean with "operates just like" is that `hjkl` cause anything scrollable to scroll. That you must press "i" to go into insert mode and write text,...

If that does not exist, does something similar at least exist for a terminal emulator?

Comment: Hi Bourgond Aries, and welcome. Unfortunately, questions seeking product recommendations are off topic on Super User. You may however have better luck on our sister site [softwarerecs.se]. "Flag" your question for moderator attention and request migration if you want it moved there.

Comment: I kicked it back here since its OT for SR. Kiiinda forgot to reopen it. Fixed. This question is certainly on tipic here.

Comment: FWIW, `hjkl` don't scroll, they move the cursor (and they are quite bad at it). I suggest getting more comfortable with Vim before wanting Vim everywhere.

Comment: @romainl: "are quite bad at it", what does this mean? You are right, they move the cursor. I was not being pedantic enough.

Comment: They move the cursor one-cell-at-a-time.

Comment: @romainl: what is a cell? Google doesn't appear to know.

Comment: Vim's screen is a grid. Each character fits in a cell of that grid. `hjkl` only move cell-by-cell with an optional count. Vim has many *vastly* better ways to move around.

Comment: @romainl: Such as ctrl+d|u, gg, G, b, w, e, ^, $, etc.? I don't see why moving cell-by-cell is especially bad. In some cases it can be useful.

Comment: In "some" cases, yes. In general, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no system-wide solution; it has to be implemented by the appliction you want to use, or a plugin for it.

The `bash` shell does have a `vi`-style input mode which you can activate with `set -o vi`. With it, h and k allow you to search in our command history (not quite the same as scrolling, but can be useful anyway). This is in fact implemented by the readline library, and thus some other readline-using applications support it too.

There is a plugin for firefox called 'vimperator', which does pretty much the same thing as vimium for chrome.

GNU Emacs has a few `vi` modes too, although that quite defeats the purpose.

The `less` pager allows scrolling with hjkl.

I'm sure there's more, this is just what I could think of...

Comment: Actually, using a vi mode for Emacs, such as evil-mode, lets you get two things, both at the same time: 1) The power of Emacs. 2) The nice keybindings of vi.  I encourage you to [edit] your answer and point this out, though of course it's up to you.  I also encourage you to try out evil-mode and see how you like it.  (Disclosure:  I contributed to a predecessor of evil-mode.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to get vi controls system-wide on modern PCs.

If you want, you can install [vim-anywhere](https://github.com/cknadler/vim-anywhere) and/or [homesick-vi-everywhere](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/homesick-vi-everywhere).  They are both useful, but they don't quite let you use the vi controls system-wide.

Still, there are dozens of applications (web browsers, PDF viewers, IDEs, etc.) which are controllable using vi controls.  (Note:  A special plugin may be required.)

Visit the TextEditors.org wiki's [ViFamily page](http://texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?ViFamily).  Scroll down to the "vi implementations that run inside other applications" section, which begins about halfway down the page.  Please also edit that wiki page and add your own contributions.